# InvalidArgument=Value of '6' is not valid for index. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I created a Listview control with 8 columns. When I need to retrieve text from subitem of Item, I use the following code:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listViewStatus.Items)
            {
                if (item.Tag == f)
                {
                    /* Use locking to synchronise across mutilple thread calls. */
                    lock (_lockObject)
                    {
                        item.SubItems[6].Text = Status;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

it shows an exception. But when I replace item.SubItems[6].Text with item.SubItems[5].Text  it works. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check how many times are item.SubItems has? perhaps item.SubItems.Count()?

Comment: It show 6. But i have 8 column

Comment: Oh. When i create SubItem i only create 6. :D

Comment: Have you filled out all the columns with an subitem via listView.SubItems.Add() ?

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem but if this is WPF or Winforms (Which it seemslike it is), there shouldnt be multiple threads accessing your listview in the first place. A ground principle of WPF and Winforms is that only the creator thread should access controls. This is most likely also related to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have at most 6 columns in SubItems

Answer (score 0):

If you've only created 6, then the values are 0-5; meaning 6 is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic "off-by-one" error scenario.

Indicies come in two flavors: Zero-based, and One-based. C# is a zero-based index language. I assume you're either learning a language for the first time, or learning a zero-based language for the first time - Otherwise, I'm missing the point of the question, and I apologize. :)

See Wikipedia, Off-By-One Error: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

The ArgumentOutOfRange exception is thrown by the runtime when it realizes that there is no 7th item in the list. This kind of error cannot be caught at compile time (without using heuristics), due to the fact that the list may contain any number of values at any time

**TLRD;**

Zero-Based (C#):

```
... = myList[0]; // This is a zero-based indexer.
... = myList[1];
... = myList[2];
... = myList[3];
... = myList[4];
... = myList[5]; // This is the 6th item, although the index is 5.
```

One-Based (some other language):

```
... = myList[1]; // This is a one-based indexer.
... = myList[2];
... = myList[3];
... = myList[4];
... = myList[5];
... = myList[6]; // This is the 6th item, and the index is 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SubItems[6]
```

`6` there represents the column index not the index of a row.